# why does my div not wrap properly?

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty simple setup as can be seen in [my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/glpoOGYZ0ntLfWf6jFIs?p=preview)

this is my html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></div>
  <div class="label">Some Label</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="link">Some link</div>
    <div class="warning">This is some long warning that should wrap on overflow</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the `controls` section to wrap, and prevent the container from wrapping.

So I wrote this CSS

```
.container{
  white-space:nowrap;
  &>div{
    display:inline-block;
  }  

  .controls{
    white-space:initial;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    &>div{
      display:inline-block;
    }
  }
  color:red; 

}
```

But what happens is that the controls div does not wrap properly.
You can see it if you preview in "windowed" mode and resize the window. It takes a while until the div recognizes it should wrap.

For a while there, some of the "long warning" is partially hidden instead of wrapping.

Here is what I see

[image]

As you can see the word `overflow` is truncated. I wanted that element to wrap inside `.controls` but it does not do that.

How can I make this work?

Comment: I'm not yet sure why this happens, but you can float `.controls` `.label` and `.checkbox` left to more or less achieve the desired result

Comment: this happens because of the `.container {white-space:nowrap}` if you remove that, everything works fine. except because the link is sibling with the `.warning` in `controls` , if `warning` doesn't fit, the whole `controls` will go on a new line. that's how css works

Comment: Same result, but @MihaiT  makes more sense

Comment: What is that & > div stuff, css inside css? Does that work?

Comment: @Valius79 it's sass.. and it works. I verified.

Comment: @MihaiT - but `.warning` should not fit inside `.controls` and then wrap inside it.. but that does not happen. shouldn't that work too?

Comment: well the children inherit the styles from the parent. it's like setting `opacity:0` to `parent` and `opacity:1` to child. the child won't show up even if it has `opacity:1` same thing here

Comment: @MihaiT but eventually it does wrap.. so what gives?

Answer (score 0):

I have just copied your code to a fiddle and tweaked it there, using `flex-box`. I am not 100% sure if I really understood what the exact problem is, but probably it helps.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hbj4vfc5/)